# is there any way to increase the limit of data using Get method in MVC4?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

in MVC4 ,i am sending ajax call to server that holds much data :

```
$.ajax({

           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           method: 'get',
           url: "Gateway/DB_Rola?count="+(n+1),
           data: things[n],
           success: function (Data) {
                                    },
           error: function () {
           alert("ERROR: can't connect to Server this time :"+n+" "+things[n].verse);
           return false;
           }
      });
```

sometimes it gives error due to massive data. is there anyway to  increase the limit of data using `get` request ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It's just an example,I have same problem

```
public JsonResult GelAllProductManagement()
    {
        var data = _taskProduct.GetAllProductListManagement(null);
         var jsonResult = Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

This is my ajax request controller, add this line in your controller for massive records

```
 var jsonResult = Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
             jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
```

This will handle your massive request.